# KQL: query all variables in dynamic column additional to existing columns

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm working with Microsoft azure Appinsights, and want to export Logs data to a CSV so I can analyze it with python. The problem is that there is one column named customDimensions, which is of dynamic type with a lot of important variables, which I want to have as separate columns. Furthermore, am I working with a lot of data, so I can't just hardcode the variables I want using 'extend', because every customDimensions value could consist of different variables.

I found online that using bag_unpack comes near the solution I want:

```
union customEvents, pageViews
| project customDimensions
| evaluate bag_unpack(customDimensions)
```

However, this outputs only the new columns, not additional to the already existing columns. But when I don't use the 'project customDimensions' line, I get the following error:

*("evaluate bag_unpack(): the following error(s) occurred while evaluating the output schema: evaluate bag_unpack(): cannot add column named 'cloud_RoleName' as it already exists in expression source")*

The question is: How do I query to get all the variables in customDimensions as additional columns, instead of having it as a dictionary in the dataframe like this:

[Dataframe with nested data instead of separate columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8fhX.png)

[Want I want from the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P9od.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're having a collision between bag_unpack() output and columns already existing in the source of bag_unpack(). Depending on what you end-goal is:

- If you want to keep both columns: use project-rename to rename the existing column to another name (e.g. .. | project-rename orig_cloud_RoleName = cloud_RoleName )
- If you want to remove column from the source: use project-away (e.g. .. | project-away cloud_RoleName)

Comment: If a variable in a dynamic list of a new row already exists as a column, because for example it was converted to a column in one of the previous rows, I want it to just put the value corresponding to that variable in said column. How do I do that?

Comment: Look at the picture I added above for a visualisation of what I want.

Comment: You can't achieve it with bag_unpack() implementation as it is today.
(If columns are known - you can use 'extend' operator to add additional columns.)
Please suggest and upvote feature at https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice